# Color changed event on Color Dialog

Tags: c#

Do we have a color changed event in the ColorDialog, that when the user changes the color value in the ColorDialog color picker the event gets fired?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such event like this. And there is no need for event like this. [Here's an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.colordialog?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) of how you should use this dialog.
If you'd want to create such event, you'd have to recreate the entire window and make the event yourself.